# Using modal 'showOpenDialog" and then opening a modal window only works once

Tags: javascript, electron

**Electron v8.1.1 – macOS 10.14.5**

I recently updated an older project to use `Electron` 8.1.1 and I am running into an issue with using a modal [showOpenDialog](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogsyncbrowserwindow-options) and then opening a modal window with the filepicker result.

It works the first time through but if, after closing the modal window, I try to do it again, it fails –  I get a system 'beep' when trying to open the filepicker (calling the `showPDFPicker` function below.

I've tried to debug it but it gets deep into the `Electron` code and just exits without error – just the system "beep". It's as if the modal dialog never closed.

If I call the filepicker with `null` instead of a parent window, the routine works as expected:

```
dialog.showOpenDialog(null, options)
```

Has anyone encountered this with `Electron` v8+? It used to work in prior versions (afaik). I tried putting in a `setTimeOut` call to delay opening the modal window for a 1000 ms, thinking that maybe there was some clean up time needed – but that did not help.

I built a test project and stripped out all other code but am still getting the failure.

I'd like the `showOpenDialog` filepicker to be modal so I'm hoping it's a problem with my code and not a bug in `Electron`.

---

**main.js**

```
function showPDFPicker() {
    var options = {
        title: 'Select PDF',
        properties: ['openFile'],
        filters: [{ name: 'PDF', extensions: ['pdf'] }],
        defaultPath: app.getPath("desktop")
    }

    dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, options)
        .then(result => {
            if (result.canceled == false) {
                filePickerCallback(result.filePaths)
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('ERROR', err);
        });

    function filePickerCallback(filenames) {        
        if (filenames && filenames.length > 0) {
            createPDFConvertWindow(filenames[0]);
        }
    }
}


function createPDFConvertWindow(pdfFile) {
    pdfConvertWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        parent: mainWindow,
        modal: true,
        show: false,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        backgroundColor: '#cccccc',
        center: true,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

    var theUrl = path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'import-dialog.html');
    pdfConvertWindow.loadFile(theUrl);

    pdfConvertWindow.on('ready-to-show', () => {
        pdfConvertWindow.show();
    })
}
```